# PHP POST to API with JSON Body and Auth

Tags: php, html, json, curl, php-curl

I am in the process of creating a super simple PHP page that sends JSON data to an remote API via POST. I am having issues with it and hoping someone here could help me out.

This is what I have so far

```
   $url = "https://remoteHost.com/api/post";
   $json = '{"message":"textHere", "user":"userABC"}';
   $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic --ACB123-ABC123---ABC123---',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),)
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
```

When I execute this nothing happens. The page loads without errors but it looks like the curl isn't actually doing anything. Any Ideas?

Comment: you are missing `"` and `;` in first line:-  `$url = "https://remoteHost.com/api/post`  . It need to be `$url = "https://remoteHost.com/api/post";`

Comment: That was a copy/paste error. I just fixed it.

Comment: Now you are missing `'` and `;` in second line. It need to be:- `$json = '{"message":"textHere", "user":"userABC"}';`

Comment: :/ Sorry about that. Its fixed. I typed that manually after I pasted the code below that.